# Schwarz Reflection Principle for function complex on the real line

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, contour-integration, analyticity

The Schwarz reflection principle is usually proved for function real on the real (or a subset of) line. I wonder if the same principle/theorem works for general analytic functions on the real line?

So I guess my question is: does the SRP hold for a function analytic in the upper half plane with a branch cut along the positive real line, but with the condition that this function can take on complex values on its branch cut?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you state more precisely your assumptions? forgetting about branches for a moment, I can only interpret your question as arbitrary analytic function on upper half plane taking any values on the real axis, yes? If the image of some part of the real axis is a line segment or circular arc, then there is something to say, otherwise not as easy.